# Getting extremely poor accuracy while doing function approximation using a neural networks in PyTorch

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, approximation

I have been given a task to approximate the function 5x^3 - 10x^2 - 5x - 9 using a neural network in pytorch. The training data is the set of integers in the range [-100,100] and I have to test the trained model against a non-integer value.
For the same, I have used a neural network with some layers and activation functions and I have also used Batch Normalization. However, the approximated function is far off from the actual function and gives extremely poor results.[image: chart]

Given below is the code

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Define the polynomial function f(x) = 5x^3 - 10x^2 - 5x + 9
def polynomial_function(x):
    return 5*x**3 - 10*x**2 - 5*x + 9

# Generate training data for integers in the range [-100, 100]
x_train = np.arange(-100, 101, dtype=np.float32)
y_train = polynomial_function(x_train)

# Define an improved neural network
class PolynomialApproximator(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(PolynomialApproximator, self).__init__()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(1, 128)
        self.relu1 = nn.ReLU()
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(128, 64)
        self.relu2 = nn.ReLU()
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(64, 1)
        self.bn1 = nn.BatchNorm1d(128)
        self.bn2 = nn.BatchNorm1d(64)
        self.dropout1 = nn.Dropout(0.2)
        self.dropout2 = nn.Dropout(0.2)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.fc1(x)
        x = self.bn1(x)
        x = self.relu1(x)
        x = self.dropout1(x)
        x = self.fc2(x)
        x = self.bn2(x)
        x = self.relu2(x)
        x = self.dropout2(x)
        x = self.fc3(x)
        return x

# Instantiate the improved model, MAE loss function, and optimizer
model = PolynomialApproximator()
criterion = nn.L1Loss()  # Mean Absolute Error (MAE) loss
optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.001)  # Use Adam optimizer for better convergence
scheduler = optim.lr_scheduler.StepLR(optimizer, step_size=500, gamma=0.5)  # Learning rate scheduler

# Training loop
num_epochs = 10000

for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    model.train()

    inputs = torch.from_numpy(x_train.reshape(-1, 1))
    targets = torch.from_numpy(y_train.reshape(-1, 1))

    optimizer.zero_grad()
    outputs = model(inputs)
    loss = criterion(outputs, targets)
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()
    scheduler.step()

    if (epoch + 1) % 100 == 0:
        model.eval()
        with torch.no_grad():
            # Calculate MAE for printing accuracy
            mae = torch.mean(torch.abs(outputs - targets))

        print(f'Epoch [{epoch+1}/{num_epochs}], Loss: {loss.item():.4f}, MAE: {mae.item():.4f}')

# Evaluate the trained model on a non-integer input
x_test = torch.tensor([[90.5]])
y_test_pred = model(x_test).item()

# Compare the function output vs. the NN output
print(f"Polynomial function output at x=78.6: {polynomial_function(90.5)}")
print(f"NN output at x=78.6: {y_test_pred}")

# Plot the original function and the trained neural network
x_plot = np.linspace(-100, 100, 1000)
y_plot_original = polynomial_function(x_plot)
y_plot_approximated = model(torch.from_numpy(x_plot.reshape(-1, 1)).float()).detach().numpy()


# y_plot_approximated = y_plot_approximated-min(y_plot_approximated)/(max(y_plot_approximated)- min(y_plot_approximated))
# y_plot_original = y_plot_original-min(y_plot_original)/(max(y_plot_original)- min(y_plot_original))

x_mean, x_std = y_plot_original.mean(), y_plot_original.std()
y_mean, y_std = y_plot_approximated.mean(), y_plot_approximated.std()

y_plot_original = (y_plot_original - x_mean) / x_std
y_plot_approximated = (y_plot_approximated - y_mean) / y_std


plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
plt.plot(x_plot, y_plot_original, color='pink', label='Original Function', linewidth=2)
plt.plot(x_plot, y_plot_approximated, label='NN Approximation', linewidth=2)
# plt.scatter(x_test.item(), y_test_pred, color='blue', marker='x', label='Test Point (x=78.6)')
plt.legend()
plt.title('Improved Function Approximation using Neural Network')
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

[image: here is the output]

What am I doing wrong ?